# java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "2147483648"

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, inputmismatchexception

Below is my code

```
public class ExceptionHandling {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InputMismatchException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        try {
            a = sc.nextInt();
            b = sc.nextInt();

            try {
                int c = a / b;
                System.out.println(b);

            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

My main query from the above question is, when I am passing String as input then I am getting `java.util.InputMismatchException` only.
But when I am passing 2147483648 as an input, it gives `java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "2147483648"` as an output.

So can anyone tell me why I am getting `For input string: "2147483648"` in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My main issue is, while passing "hello" the output is java.util.InputMismatchException. But while passing (2147483648) long in int type the output is= java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "2147483648". I want to know why is it printing extra content.

That is a different question to what you were originally asking, but I will answer anyway.

The reason you are getting "extra content" as in:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "2147483648"
```

is that you are printing the exception like this:

```
System.out.println(e);
```

This calls `toString()` on the exception object and prints it.  The `toString()` method for a typical exception is roughly equivalent to this:

```
public String toString() {
    return e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage();
}
```

If you don't want the exception name, just print the exception message:

```
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

which would output:

```
For input string: "2147483648"
```

(IMO, that is not the kind of message you should be showing to users. It doesn't explain anything!)

---

> I want the output to be same for both Hello and 2147483648.

It will be, I think.  For "Hello", the output will be:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "Hello"
```

---

Finally, if you actually want an intelligible error message, you will need to make more extensive modifications to the code.  Unfortunately, neither `nextInt()` or `Integer.parseInt(...)` give exception messages that explain *why* an input string is not an acceptable `int` value.

Comment: Thanks man your answer was helpful, by using System.out.println(e.getClass().getName()); it helped me

Answer (score 1):

The value `2147483648` is larger than the maximum value which can fit into a primitive Java integer, which is `2147483647`. Java integers only fit any value between -2147483648 and 2147483647 [-2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, since java int is a 32-bit integer]. To get around this problem, either use an input within range for integers, or maybe use a wider type, such as `long`:

```java
long a = 0;
long b = 0;

try {
    a = sc.nextLong();
    b = sc.nextLong();
    // ...
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

Comment: Yeah I understand what you are saying, it is out of range for int, i get that. But my main issue is, while passing "hello" the output is java.util.InputMismatchException. But while passing (2147483648) long in int type the output is= java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: “2147483648”. I want to know why is it printing extra content. I want the output to be same for both Hello and 2147483648.

Comment: Well passing an out of range value to an integer and passing a string are both triggering the same exception.  Why do you need anything finer grain than this?

Comment: It's a programming question on Hackerrank,the output should be same for both string and 2147483648. The exception is same in both cases, but for string it is=java.util.InputMismatchException & for  2147483648 it is =java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: “2147483648”..I dont know why it is printing (For input string: “2147483648”).

Answer (score 1):

The exception message includes the string value itself to give more insight about the mistake because the "2147483648" string is a string that resembles an integer but cannot be represented as one because of its size. The string value for "hello," on the other hand, is obviously not an integer, thus it is unnecessary to include it in the exception message.